# How to open a Python 3 Program in another folder within Python 3

Tags: python

I would like to open a Python 3 program within Python 3, but the target program is in another folder.

EG: Pythonloader.py > PythonFolder > Target.py

I am using Python 3.3.0

Comment: What does "open" mean? Launch as if you launched it manually? `import` the module? Why is the separate folder specifically such an issue?

Comment: Organisation is important.

Comment: That's not answering any of my questions.

Comment: "Why is the separate folder specifically such an issue" I did.

Comment: That's not an answer... Anyway, what about the other questions?

Comment: There may be a language barrier here… *What exactly* is the problem with using another folder? Would you be able to solve this problem if the program was within the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subprocess module to run any external program:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python3 /path/to/target.py')
```

Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html for a review.

If you want to import the code to use within your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/containing/directory')
import target
```

Then you can use the code within.

Comment: This works very well. I am using this for a central python program to open the rest for school efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I was able to guess the 4 numbers and it stopped correctly for me. Looks like you wrote the program correctly but you aren't able to guess the numbers as well.

```
$ python foo.py
First >> 1
Second >> 2
Third >> 3
Fourth >> 4
*
First >> 5
Second >> 6
Third >> 7
Fourth >> 8

First >> 1
Second >> 1
Third >> 1
Fourth >> 1
**
First >> 2
Second >> 2
Third >> 2
Fourth >> 2
*
First >> 3
Second >> 3
Third >> 3
Fourth >> 3

First >> 4
Second >> 4
Third >> 4
Fourth >> 4
*
First >> 1
Second >> 1
Third >> 2
Fourth >> 4
**
First >> 1
Second >> 2
Third >> 1
Fourth >> 4
*
First >> 1
Second >> 1
Third >> 4
Fourth >> 2
*
First >> 4
Second >> 1
Third >> 1
Fourth >> 2

First >> 1
Second >> 4
Third >> 1
Fourth >> 2
**
First >> 1
Second >> 4
Third >> 2
Fourth >> 1
****
```

Comment: I have tried every possible number and still doesn't work.

Comment: your code is correct, but you need to guess more intelligently .. ask some friend to try